# Wordpress uploads folder permission issue

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

We recently made an upgrade (in Oct) to Wordpress 4.3.1. We have been using DSO for the PHP handler, before and after upgrade. The upgrade was carried out manually as 'root'.

But since the upgrade, we are not able to upload Media files into the "wp/wp-content/uploads" folder with 755 (or) 775 permissions. It is required to have 777 permissions. This wasn't the case before the upgrade.

Checked the ownership of all folders/files under wordpress, everything shows cpanel user as the user:group, nothing is owned by 'root'. Similarly, only those folders within 'uploads' that has been granted 777 permssions has ownership as 'nobody:nobody'.

What could have caused the changes with 'uploads' folder ever since the upgrade?

Comment: Does your wp-content and upload folders permission is 777 now?

Comment: Are you using shared hosting? If yes, contact the provider.
If you have SSH access to the server, try "ls -la" and see if the user and user group is correct.

Note: Don't use 777 permission, if the ownership is correct, then it doesn't requires 777.